# List in chrome not being fully rendered

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, vue.js

I'm having what appears to be a rendering problem in Chrome.
I have a scrollable ul block that contains ~230 li items, each 80px tall, that is clipped by a white rectangle around the 70th item, until the end.
The clipping area does not appear in the inspector, it is purely visual.
The hidden content is also still perfectly accessible and clickable, like normal.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

The problem only appears in Chrome (MacOS), not even Chromium, and depends on the height of the viewport. Toggling the inspector, for example, will change the rendered height without any logic.

I tried to toggle pretty much every CSS that is applied to the related divs, without any success. I can't really post any code here since I don't know which part is responsible, but I'd be happy to if you have any clue.

Also, I'm using `vue.js;` the items are rendered by a v-for loop, I don't know if this is relevant here.

Comment: Are you using any memory cleaners on mac (CCleaner, Dr Cleaner, etc)? Might be that they clean Chrome's cache when you render a lot of elements.

Comment: I am using OnyX, but I don't think it's supposed to clean files dynamically ... ?
The problem also seems to appear on a Mac that does not have any cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the ul or its parent has position: relative. If there is, take away should help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).